# Not getting connection string in Other classes in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

In Connection class

```cs
public Connection(IConfiguration _Configuration)
{
    dbConnectionString = _Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
}
```

In Startup class on Configure  Method

```cs
services.AddDbContext<Models.AwardContext>(option =>
option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should firstly add `Configuration` as a `Singleton` in `ConfigureServices`:

```
 services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration);
```